# Object state change in overridden function not reflected in base class function

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

I think this should be obvious but for some reason it's not making sense to me.

```
public class Foo extends Sprite
{
    protected var dict:Dictionary = new Dictionary();

    protected function subclassBehavior():void
    {
        //defined in subclass
    }
    public function accessDictionary():void
    {      
        subclassBehavior();

        var i:int = 0;
        for each(var value:Object in dict)  
        {
            i++;
        }
        trace(i);
    }
}
```

Simple enough.

Then the subclass:

```
public class Bar extends Foo
{
    override protected function subclassBehavior():void
    {
        dict["a"] = "b";
    }
}
```

And then if I do:

```
var instance:Foo = new Bar();
instance.accessDictionary();
```

I'd expect the trace to return 1.  Instead it returns 0.  The entry in the dict just doesn't exist as far as any methods in Foo are concerned.  If I have another function in Bar that looks at dict, it will see the entry.  I've tried instantiating the dictionary in Bar and passing it to Foo, changing the call in Bar to call a method in Foo that updates the dictionary, etc, none of this seems to change my situation.

Do I need to override any and all functionality in the base class that I want to reflect other overridden behavior in the subclass?

Comment: I tested your code and it printed 1 for me.

Comment: What happens when you put a breakpoint in `subcassBehavior()` and look at the value of `dict`?

Comment: This is an extreme simplification of the actual code, but if it should be working I can look for other sources of the problem, thanks.  Just wanted to confirm it's not some weird expected polymorphism behavior in AS3.

Comment: This might indeed be a compiler issue, there's a question nearby that states his compiler throws `overriding a function that's not marked for override` error against a construction like this pair of classes. Perhaps adding `override` to `subclassBehavior()` function description will do. It does for me, FlashDevelop 3.4.3 is the compiler.

Comment: @JonBarone I have tested you sample and the trace returns me 1. Are you sure you do not have some kind of special comfiguration. Which IDE are you using and which flash version ?

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure if for each is working with dictionary.
you can try

```
for(var key:String in dict)
{
  i++;
}
```